# Drag and drop disabled in windows 10 - not working in app and file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, drag-and-drop

I cant even begin drag of any items objects files.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I got the same issue sometimes. It is global to all applications (cannot drag-drop a file in explorer, nor moving an email in outlook, etc...). The only solution I have now is a reboot and everything is fine after.

Answer (score 0):

There could be numerous reasons why Drag and Drop stopped functioning.

**(1) First fix:**

Try DISM / SFC

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(2) Fix** if DISM fails to help.

**Run a Windows 10 Repair Install**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. **The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.**  Use the default .

**(3) Fix if all fails:**

If everything above fails to produce results, your OS is more seriously damaged, or, your Windows User Profile is damaged.

Either way, back up everything and reinstall Windows 10.